# CompositeException in Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2

When I request data from the server, almost cases rxjava can catch exception in my rxjava chain, but sometimes the onError() cannot handle the exception.

And here are my related libraries:

```
io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.14
io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2
com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.4.0
com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
```

crash with exceptions below:

```
io.reactivex.exceptions.CompositeException: 
  at io.reactivex.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.onError (LambdaObserver.java:80)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.checkTerminated (ObservableObserveOn.java:276)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.drainNormal (ObservableObserveOn.java:172)
  at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.run (ObservableObserveOn.java:252)
  at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run (HandlerScheduler.java:109)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:873)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:193)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6898)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:537)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: Could you please show relevant code?

Comment: public static void errorHandler(Activity activity, Throwable error) {
if (error instanceof SocketTimeoutException) {
SnackToaster.snack(activity, "Connection Timed Out");
}else if (error instanceof ConnectException) {
SnackToaster.snack(activity, "Please enable Wifi or Mobile data");
}else {
SnackToaster.snack(activity, "Connection Error");
}

}

Comment: `CompositeException` has several exceptions within it. Can you please check which ones are in this one? They're also printed when the stacktrace is printed. Thank you very much!